# F# Summing all ints in a list

Tags: list, recursion, f#

Given a `list` of `int`s, I want to return the sum of all the elements in the `list` which satisfy some predicate `p`.

I have come this far, but it isn't quite there yet. The compiler complains on `0` with the message: `The type 'int' does not match the type 'int list -> 'a''`

```
let sum (p, xs) =
    let rec sum' p xs tempSum = function
        | []        -> tempSum
        | x::xs     -> sum' p xs tempSum + (if p x then x else 0)
    sum' p xs 0
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `List.filter p |> List.sum` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sum'` function isn't pattern matching on the `xs` variable, to fix it ise the `match ... with` syntax where the `...` is the variable that you wish to match on (in your case `xs`) - the type mismatch should be resolved by that.

Answer (score 2):

```
let sum p xs =
    xs 
    |> List.sumBy (fun x -> if p x then x else 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's one other mistake in your code that you haven't noticed because it's producing the same result. As it's currently written, your code isn't tail-recursive, even though you've tried to make it so. That's because function application has tighter precedence than operators like `+`. So the expression `sum' p xs tempSum + (if p x then x else 0)` in your code is being interpreted as:

```
(sum' p xs tempSum) + (if p x then x else 0)
```

when what you probably wanted was:

```
sum' p xs (tempSum + (if p x then x else 0))
```

The way you wrote it, the result of the nested `sum'` call can't be immediately returned since the addition happens after the recursive call returns, so each call takes a stack frame, and your code would fail on a list of thousands of items. By adding the parentheses around your addition, you'll get the tail call optimization you were probably expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum f =  List.fold (fun s x -> if f x then s + x else s) 0
```

Or, if tail recursion is required

```
let sum f xs =
    let rec aux acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | x::xs when f x -> aux (x + acc) xs
        | _::xs -> aux acc xs
    aux 0 xs
```